# How do I check for a null or empty item in a ListView SubItem?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have created this listview box that when contents are double clicked the values are inserted into text boxes. There are spaces in some items and a couple have null values in the subitems.  When these particular list items are clicked it crashes the software. Is there a way I can check if a subitem is null or empty?

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    For i As Integer = 1 To 7
        Dim tbName As String = "TextBox" & i
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(tbName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
            If tb.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                tb.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a subitem is null or empty, you could add something like this line of code:

```
If tb.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
      'check if subitem isn't null and its text is not ""
       If Not IsNothing(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0)) AndAlso ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text <> "" Then
            tb.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
            Exit Sub
       End if
End If
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: You can combine both of those checks into one by using String.IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: @BenR, I was checking to make sure the actual subitem isn't null, but I guess I didn't realize that `subitems(0)` can't be null (at least as far as I know). Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some validation to`ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text`

It seems to be null sometimes:

Use this validation:

```
If Not ListView1.SelectedItems is Nothing
   AndAlso Not ListView1.SelectedItems(0) is Nothing
   AndAlso Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text)  Then

                tb.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
End if
```

**Full code:**

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    For i As Integer = 1 To 7
        Dim tbName As String = "TextBox" & i
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(tbName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
            If tb.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
              If Not ListView1.SelectedItems is Nothing
                     AndAlso Not ListView1.SelectedItems(0) is Nothing
                     AndAlso Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text)  Then
                tb.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
              End if
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: cool thanks, the two lines beggining with AndAlso have syntax errors

Comment: This is not a code writing service. I answered from mobile so maybe some character could be wrong. You need to apply the idea not to copy/ paste